# JavaScript and URL parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using JQuery to push data to Google Analytics when the Ajax code is fired.

I need some help in capturing checkboxes with the same ID name.  Basically, it's overwriting previous values with the last checkbox selected.  Can someone help modify my code below to see if the checkbox is checked, and instead of overwriting, appending the value?

```
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
// If the decode flag is present, URL decode the set
    var item = decode ? decodeURIComponent(arr[i]) : arr[i];
    var pair = item.split(spl);
    var key = trim_(pair[0]);
    var value = trim_(pair[1]);
    if (key && value) {
        obj[key] = value;
        }
    }
```

This is what part of my URL parameters looks like:

> /ordersearch?soldToList=1001014377%7C1000%7CSP&shipToList=1001000903%7C1000%7CSH&startDate=03%2F22%2F2016&endDate=03%2F23%2F2016&orderStatus=Complete&
>   _orderStatus=on& orderStatus=Cancelled&
>   _orderStatus=on& orderStatus=Open&
>   _orderStatus=on& productStatus=COMPLETE&
>   _productStatus=on& productStatus=Cancelled&
>   _productStatus=on& productStatus=OPEN&
>   _productStatus=on& ponumber=8940324& materialnumber=98574395& ordernumber=7493278

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I don't see any jQuery and thus I'm advising you to stick with dom selectors for this.

You can use `document.getElementById('checkboxId').checked`, which returns a boolean value, to see if the checkbox with *checkboxId* is checked.

Appending elements can be achieved like so; `div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + 'Extra stuff';`

Your question and code combination are vague at best so I would recommend getting your logic right and only concentrating on syntax once you know exactly how you're going to achieve your goal.